# Unit test of DAO layer with mockito

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I am trying to use Mockito for unit testing of my Spring + Hibernate project. Following is the implementation of my DAO class:

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        System.out.println("Session factory");
    }
    @Override
    public ArrayList<Employees> getAllData() {
        System.out.println("Inside get all data");
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println("session created");
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Employees.class, "employees").setResultTransformer(
                Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

        return (ArrayList<Employees>) cr.list();
    }

}
```

Following is my test class:

```
public class EmployeeDAOImplTest {

    @Mock
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Mock
    private Session session;
    @Mock
    Criteria criteria;
    @Spy
    ArrayList<Employees> employees = new ArrayList<Employees>();

    private EmployeeDAO dao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        dao = new EmployeeDAOImpl();
        dao.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        employees = getEmpDetails();
        Mockito.doReturn(session).when(sessionFactory).getCurrentSession();

    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAllData() {
        Mockito.doReturn(criteria).when(session)
                .createCriteria(ConceptModelDetails.class);
        Mockito.doReturn(employees).when(criteria).list();
            assertEquals(employees, dao.getAllData());
    }

    private ArrayList<Employees> getEmpDetails() {
        ArrayList<Employees> array = new ArrayList<Employees>();
        Employees emp = new Employees();
        emp.setName("xyz");
        emp.setId(12);
        array.add(cm);
        return array;
    }

}
```

`employees` is the dummy array list of Employees. Please suggest what is he issue here.When I run this test case, I am getting a failure with Null Pointer Exception in :

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Employees.class, "employees").setResultTransformer(
                    Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.assignment.dao.impl.EmployeeDAOImpl.getAllData(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:77)
    at com.assignment.DAOTest.EmployeeDAOImplTest.testGetAllData(EmployeeDAOImplTest.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Always include the stack trace.

Comment: (And for that matter, consider using Spring Data instead of writing DAOs by hand.)

Comment: Why is employees a @Spy ? and why are you instantiating it in the declaration?

Comment: @chrylis Done. Could you please elaborate on that(using spring data)?

Comment: @IkerObregonReigosa Please ignore Spy.

Comment: mentioned stack trace has nothing in common with EmployeeDAOImpl or EmployeeDAOImplTest classes, it points to ConceptModelDAOImpl and ConceptModelDAOImplTest

Comment: Just read the docs and Getting Started guides for Spring Data. It writes your DAOs for you.

Comment: @CroWell Apologies. That was from the identical project. I have made the changes.

Comment: You are testing JAVA, but not your DAO ... Effectively you test if delegating to cr.list() is working ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EmployeeDAOImpl` contains the following code:

```
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Employees.class, "employees").setResultTransformer(
            Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Your test has:

```
    Mockito.doReturn(criteria).when(session)
            .createCriteria(ConceptModelDetails.class);
```

You are correctly mocking out `sessionFactory` and the `session` that it is returning, as far as I can tell from your code.  However, you are not correctly mocking out `session.createCriteria(Employee.class, "employees")` (instead, you are setting the return value for `session.createCriteria(ConceptModelDetails.class)`).  Therefore, the return value from the mock will be `null`.  So when you dereference it immediately (calling `setResultTransformer`), you will get a `NullPointerException`.

To verify this, try stepping into the debugger, or adding log statements to `EmployeeDAOImpl`, that show the values of `sessionFactory`, `session`, and the result from `session.createCriteria(...)`.