# Correct configuration to mock Hibernate's sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@HibernateProfile
public class PersonaHibernateRepository implements PersonaRepository {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonaHibernateRepository.class.getSimpleName());

    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public PersonaHibernateRepository(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        logger.info("{} constructor", PersonaHibernateRepository.class.getSimpleName());
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public Persona saveOne(Persona persona) {
        String generatedIdentifier = (String) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(persona);
        logger.info("generatedIdentifier: {}", generatedIdentifier);
        return persona;
    }

...
```

Each `crud` method has `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

With `Mockito` the following sentence:

```
when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(persona)).thenReturn(persona.getId());
```

always throws `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I've confirmed `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` is the point of the problem.

I already have read the following:

- [Mocking Hibernate Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583346/mocking-hibernate-session)
- [Unit test of DAO layer with mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199388/unit-test-of-dao-layer-with-mockito)

Thus the `java.lang.NullPointerException` was removed.

But I always get now:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Wanted 1 time:
-> at com.manuel.jordan.repository.hibernate.PersonaHibernateRepositoryTest_.saveOneTest(PersonaHibernateRepositoryTest_.java:76)
But was 2 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at com.manuel.jordan.repository.hibernate.PersonaHibernateRepository.saveOne(PersonaHibernateRepository.java:43)
```

These two times happens due the mock invocation and target invocation.

Currently my configuration is:

```
private PersonaHibernateRepository personaHibernateRepository;
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private Session session;

...

@Before
public void setup(){
    sessionFactory = mock(SessionFactory.class);
    session = mock(Session.class);
    personaHibernateRepository = new PersonaHibernateRepository(sessionFactory);
    //Removes NullPointerException - 'A'
    when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
}

@Test
public void saveOneTest(){

    //java.lang.NullPointerException removed thanks to 'A'      
    when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(persona)).thenReturn(persona.getId());

    Persona persona_ = personaHibernateRepository.saveOne(persona);
    assertThat(persona_, is(persona));

    //B
    verify(sessionFactory).getCurrentSession().save(persona);
}
```

Just playing, if I change:

From: `verify(sessionFactory).getCurrentSession().save(persona);`

To: `verify(sessionFactory, times(2)).getCurrentSession().save(persona);` (observe `times(2)`)

Again appears the `java.lang.NullPointerException` thrown **now** by `verify(sessionFactory, times(2)).getCurrentSession().save(persona);` (`B`)

Same exception if in `@Before` the `when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session)` is changed to `doReturn(session).when(sessionFactory).getCurrentSession()`

What is the correct configuration?

Comment: `verify(sessionFactory).getCurrentSession().save(persona);` should be `verify(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).save(persona);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `setup()` method you correctly tell Mockito to return the mocked `session` instance when `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` is invoked so from them on your assertions should focus on the `session` instance not the `sessionFactory`. For example:

```
@Test
public void saveOneTest(){
    // you have already told Mockito to return this session instance when sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() is 
    // invoked so now your when (and optionally verify) should focus on session rather than on sessionFactory
    when(session.save(persona)).thenReturn(persona.getId());

    Persona persona_ = personaHibernateRepository.saveOne(persona);
    assertThat(persona_, is(persona));

    verify(session).save(persona);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works, now something is confuse for me, and I never seen this approach or behavior in none tutorial, I thought that for Mockito is mandatory do the `when/thenReturn` and `verify` respecting or reflecting the **same** code being used in the `saveOne` method. `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(persona);`. Consider add an extra explanation about that for the community

Comment: It's not mandatory to use both `when/thenReturn` **and** `verify` for the same method-under-test. A `verify` call allows you to assert that a method was called on your mocked object and to verify the arguments passed to that method call. A `when/thenReturn` indirectly allows the same thing but with the additional side effect of allowing that mocked object to participate in your code flow as if it was a real object. So they can be used to achieve the same thing although it's also true that there are scenarios where one is perferred to the other but it's not true that they must be used together.

Comment: Interesting and thanks by the explanation, just curious if it is reflected in the current mockito documentation. I am considering create an issue to improve its documentation.

Comment: Just to be in the same picture, the `saveOne` method contains the `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(persona)` sentence, but in `when/thenReturn` and `verify` calls, they work *directly* around the `Session` instead.